# If $N \unlhd G$ has index $n$ in $G$, then $g^n \in N$ for all $g \in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups

If $N \unlhd G$ has index $n$ in $G$, then $g^n \in N$ for all $g \in G$.

My proof attempt:

As $N$ is normal and has index $n$ in $G$, this means $G/N$ has size $n$ then elements of the form $gN$ to the power of $n$ are $e$, that is

\begin{align}
g^nN&=(gN)^n &&\text{definition of binary operation in quotient group}\\
&=eN &&\text{as $\vert G/N \vert = n$}\\
&=N && \text{every group absorbs $e$}
\end{align}

and as $N$ is a subgroup we have that $g^nN=N$ iff $g^n \in N$ and this was for arbitrary $g \in G$ thus we are done.

Btw I wasn't sure if there was already a solution for this but I came up with this on my own so I really wanna know if I am on the right track.

Comment: Where do you think this might possibly be wrong?

Comment: @KCd I don't know, that's why I posted my attempted solution. it looks ok to me lol.

Comment: The idea is correct. Only thing, why $g^nN=eN$? You didn't really explain it formally. Actually, it makes more sense to write it in a different order, as $g^nN=(gN)^n=eN=N$, where the second equality follows from Lagrange's theorem. (because the order of $G/N$ is $n$. You should mention Lagrange's theorem here) After all, you wish to show that $g^nN=N$, not that $(gN)^n=N$, so that's another reason why this order of equalities makes more sense.

Comment: @Mark you're right, noted and fixed. that makes total sense.

Comment: "then elements of the form $gN$ to the power of $n$ are $e$": no, elements of the form $gN$ to the power of $n$ are $N$, as yourself, on the other hand, have written threreafter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. It is, as far a I know, the standard way to prove it.

Comment: cool, thanks!!!